# AWS API Gateway write dynamic JSON directly to DynamoDB and keep JSON structure

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-api-gateway

When I try to save a JSON object field of a JSON request as a string, directly from Amazon API Gateway to DynamoDB, the JSON gets saved without double quotes around the keys, making it invalid JSON. I'm using this mapping template:

```
      application/json: "{\"TableName\":\"Lessons\",\"Item\":{\"id\":{\"S\":\"$input.path('$.studentHistoryId')\"},\"lesson\":{\"S\":\"$util.escapeJavaScript($input.path('$.lesson'))\"}}}"
```

So if I make this request:

```
{
    "studentHistoryId": "f",
    "lesson": {
        "wow": "1",
        "test": "2",
        "problem": 3,
        "ok great": {
            "further test": "no problems here"
        }
    }
}
```

The lesson gets saved into DynamoDB as this:

```
{wow=1, test=2, problem=3, ok great={further test=no problems here}}
```

Unless I'm mistaken, I won't be able to parse that out as JSON. I need to be able to convert that back to JSON so I can later edit one of the internal fields (like "further test" for example).

Answer (score 0):

when you use the `put item` from your SDK, make sure the attribute is defined as a Map. Maps will conserve the json structure. If you don't provide an attribute type it will default to "S" or String automatically. (though from your example it seems to actually being stored as a Set rather than a String)

See [this page](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/HowItWorks.NamingRulesDataTypes.html) for more information about datatypes in attributes